# Get only rows where data is the max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
treatment | patient_id
        3 |          1
        3 |          1
        3 |          1
        2 |          1
        2 |          1
        1 |          1
        2 |          2
        2 |          2
        1 |          2
```

I need to get only rows on `max(treatment)` like this:

```
treatment | patient_id
        3 |          1
        3 |          1
        3 |          1
        2 |          2
        2 |          2
```

The `patient_id` 1 the `max(treatment)` is 3
The `patient_id` 2 the `max(treatment)` is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example join on the aggregated table using the maximal value:

```
select t.*
from tmp t
inner join (
  select max(a) max_a, b
  from tmp
  group by b
) it on t.a = it.max_a and t.b = it.b;
```

[Here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=47db83a64e861f5c313ac159e4706eab) the db fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT patient_id, max(treatment) AS treatment_max
    FROM your_table
   GROUP BY patient_id
)
SELECT *
  FROM your_table AS t
 INNER JOIN list AS l
    ON t.patient_id = l.patient_id
   AND t.treatment = l.treatment_max
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank`:

```
with u as
(select *, rank() over(partition by patient_id order by treatment desc) r
from table_name)
select treatment, patient_id
from u
where r = 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2d8b6d1313118b2d52fbb6a14bd51c1a)

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where t1.treatment=( select max(treatment) from table_name t2 where t1.patient_id=t2.patient_id
)
```